# how to map shell command line arguments to READ command

Tags: linux, shell, unix, scripting, ksh

My program takes in 2 arguments from a user

```
echo "Enter First code :"; read code_1
echo "Enter Second code :"; read code_2
```

I Run test.ksh and it prompts for user input.

Say user inputs 1 and 2

```
Enter First code : 1
Enter Second code : 2
```

Now without editing test.ksh how do I map arguments passed at command line to read statements inside my shell script ?

```
test.ksh 1 2

Enter First code : 1
Enter Second code : 2
```

Comment: when you are passing a command line argument, then whats the need of the read statement ?
assign the arguments to variables as $1, $2 and so on...

Comment: Exactly. If someone runs `./yourscript 1 2`, then you have those values in `$1` and `$2` and have no need for `read`. Only run `read` when you *don't* have the values you need from the command line.

Comment: I cannot edit the script (test.ksh) which is already working with "read" statement inside it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't; you write the values to your scripts standard input instead.

```
printf '1\n2\n' | test.ksh
```